# Run python on Linux without python installed

Tags: python-3.x

Currently I'm using cx_Freeze to turn .py into .exe and this works fine with modules and everything, but I can't find any way to make it so it could run in Linux.
Is there any alternative for making it be able to run on Linux? Using something else other than cx_Freeze is fine.

Is there any way to compile it for Linux, while on Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html?#freezing-for-other-platforms)

> cx_Freeze works on Windows, Mac and Linux, but on each platform it only makes an executable that runs on that platform. So if you want to freeze your program for Windows, freeze it on Windows; if you want to run it on Macs, freeze it on a Mac.

Comment: Yes, I know. What I meant is there any way to compile it for Linux, while on Windows. (Edited question to include this.)

Comment: Use VirtualBox and install a virtual machine with a Linux distribution

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm now doing. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should try [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).

It supports creation of self-encapsulated python executables that work even when the python runtime is not installed.